# Draw grid lines on second image

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my example, I wish to draw grid lines on the second image but now it draws on first image also:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=yellow!20}, show background rectangle]
    \tikzset{box/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0}}
    \node[box] (N1) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};

    \node[box,right=0.5cm of N1] (N2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(N2.south east)},y={(N2.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \i in {N2.south east,N2.north west} {
        \node[circle,fill=red,minimum size=20pt] at(\i) {};
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `shift={N2.south west}` to change the origin in your scope:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=yellow!20}, show background rectangle]
    \tikzset{box/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0}}
    \node[box] (N1) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};

    \node[box,right=0.5cm of N1] (N2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(N2.south west)},x={(N2.south east)},y={(N2.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \i in {N2.south east,N2.north west} {
        \node[circle,fill=red,minimum size=20pt] at(\i) {};
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is more like a work-around, place the second picture at the origin first, then place the first image relative to it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=yellow!20}, show background rectangle]
    \tikzset{box/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0}}
    \node[box] (N2) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \node[box,left=0.7cm of N2] (N1) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}};

    \begin{scope}[x={(N2.south east)},y={(N2.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \i in {N2.south east,N2.north west} {
        \node[circle,fill=red,minimum size=20pt] at(\i) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]